# Error 1093 Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

> Hello , when I try this:

```
 UPDATE SET managedBy_id=(SELECT id FROM users  as managedBy_id WHERE login=123456) WHERE login=72584;
```

> The output is: 
>     Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause  0.000 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement is wrong, modify it like

```
UPDATE users 
SET managedBy_id = CASE WHEN login=123456 THEN id ELSE managedBy_id END
WHERE login=72584;
```

Comment: there is no point doing this `update` as you are only filtering for `login=72584` and updating it to `managedBy_id`